# iostream and large file support

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, large-files, large-file-support

I'm trying to find a definitive answer and can't, so I'm hoping someone might know.

I'm developing a C++ app using GCC 4.x on Linux (32-bit OS).  This app needs to be able to read files > 2GB in size.

I would really like to use iostream stuff vs. FILE pointers, but I can't find if the large file #defines (_LARGEFILE_SOURCE, _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE, _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64) have any effect on the iostream headers.

I'm compiling on a 32-bit system.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has already been decided for you when `libstdc++` was compiled, and normally depends on whether or not `_GLIBCXX_USE_LFS` was defined in `c++config.h`.

If in doubt, pass your executable (or `libstdc++.so`, if linking against it dynamically) through `readelf -r` (or through `strings`) and see if your binary/`libstdc++` linked against `fopen`/`fseek`/etc. or `fopen64`/`fseek64`/etc.

**UPDATE**

You don't have to worry about the 2GB limit as long as you don't need/attempt to `fseek` or `ftell` (you just read from or write to the stream.)

Comment: I do have to seek/read position, but I confirmed that my c++ libs have LFS support so I can use the fstream's tell and seek calls.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GCC, you can take advantage of a GCC extension called __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf, which ties an IOStream to a standard C *FILE* descriptor.

You need to define the following two things:

> _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
>
> _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

For example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>

int main()
{
  std::ofstream outstream;
  FILE* outfile;

  outfile = fopen("bigfile", "w");

  __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> fdbuf(outfile, std::ios::out |
                                       std::ios::binary);
  outstream.std::ios::rdbuf(&fdbuf);

  for(double i = 0; i <= 786432000000.0; i++) {
    outstream << "some data";

  fclose(outfile);
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: this doesn't really solve any problems.  64-bit offset support is needed in order to be able to call ftell/fseek; for that use stdio_sync_filebuf, but that relies on _GLIBCXX_USE_LFS  having been defined