# Processing files larger than 2 GB in C++ with STL

Tags: c++, stl, fstream

I am doing binary file processing and in my algorithm I would like to know the actual type of `pos_type` and `off_type`, for example when computing the size of the file or seeking to a given position (`tellg` and `seekg`).

When computing the size of the file I just `static_cast` the `pos_type` to an `int64_t` and it seems to work fine.

How about `seekg`? Is it safe to pass an `int64_t` to it?

**Is there a way to make** `pos_type` **and** `off_type` **to be an** `int64_t`, **perhaps using** `traits`**?**

I would like to eliminate the hideous cast and find a way that is in accordance with the C++ standard.

**Update: see also**

- [Is it safe to assign pos_type to uint64_t when dealing with large files (> 2GB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8756496/341970)
- [iostream and large file support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660667/iostream-and-large-file-support)

Comment: This kind of question can't be answered in a platform independent way, because each platform is free to choose its own limits.

Comment: True, but for example it is always safe to assing an int32_t to an int64_t, or an uint32_t to an int64_t. A safe / portable solution would suffice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not all compilers have STL implementations with large file support.

For example, the following program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << numeric_limits<streamoff>::max() << endl;
}
```

results in:

- VS2005 - 2147483647
- VS2008 - 2147483647
- VS2010 - 9223372036854775807
- MinGW GCC 4.4.0 - 9223372036854775807

On the other hand [STLPort](http://stlport.sourceforge.net/) has cross platform large file support.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use std::fpos_t typedef.

Comment: It is in ctsdio and I cannot see how I could use it with fstream.