# tellg() returning negative answer

Tags: c++, file-io

I have opened a file in binary mode, and doing below operations gives negative value of x. The file that I have opened is ~2.5 GB in size.

```
infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
__int64 x = infile.tellg();
```

I needed `infile` to read bytes (unsigned chars), so I had defined it as a `uifstream` by doing:

```
typedef basic_ifstream<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char> > uifstream;
```

which is basically a standard ifstream, but with `unsigned chars` instead of `chars`.

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2005 and corrected uofstream to uifstream.

Comment: Are you using an output stream as input? `seekg` and `tellg` does only exist in input file streams.

Comment: oops.. that was a typo... corrected it now...

Comment: How did you opened the file? which options you used? Is correctly opened? Did you checked internal status flags after opening and seekg?

Comment: found something on this link, but couldn't find any solution... There is something about the 2^31 limit... http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t686780-can-ifstream-read-file-more-than-2g.html

Comment: opened the file using `ios::in | ios::binary` flags... And yes, I do a `infile.is_good()` check before which confirms that the file is open...

Comment: Maybe the implementation of the standard library uses a signed 32-bit type for the position type?

Comment: by the way, I used Visual Studio's `_stat64` function to get the file size, which returns the correct file size... but the question still remains that what is the problem with seekg() and tellg() here...

Comment: STL in VS2005 does not support large offsets, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404760/processing-files-larger-than-2-gb-in-c-with-stl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I already put this in a comment but I think it is also the answer:

STL in VS2005 does not support offsets larger than 2147483647 (~2GB) so seeking or telling the position beyond that does not work and would explain the negative values. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4404760/79455))

(Also `tellg()` returns -1 when there is an error, but I assume you are seeing other negative values)

The solution is to use a newer compiler (VS2010) or use an alternative STL implementation like  [STLPort](http://stlport.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty VS2010-compatible solution:

```
__int64 size = *(__int64*) ( ((char*)&(infile.tellg())) +8)
```