# Is it safe to assign pos_type to uint64_t when dealing with large files (> 2GB)?

Tags: c++, winapi, stl, posix, fstream

When trying to deal with large files (2/4GB) in cross-platform manner, is it safe to cast `pos_type` to `uint64_t`?

- Platforms targeted: desktop machines running current Linux distro, Windows, Mac.
- Task: random binary file access (`tellp` and `seekp`).
- Sought: solution that is closest to the standards (POSIX, Win API), portable and safe.

Comment: It is not, at least one popular compiler's library that I know of still uses 32-bit values.  Just use sizeof to find out.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, that is what I asked from James Kanze. How about the C++11 static_assert? How can I figure out the answer at compile time?

Comment: Well, sure, have you tried it?  Now also requiring the compilers to implement C++11 doesn't actually make the task any easier.

Comment: pos_type is a specialised alias of fpos - which is a class.

Comment: @JaredKrumsie Although I can happily convert it to an `uint64_t`. See also the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice or in theory.  As far as the standard is concerned, I don't
think that there is a guarantee that `pos_type` is even convertible to
an integral type; logically, it shouldn't be, since it contains several
independent data: the offset from the beginning of the file **and**
state information for multibyte decoding.

In practice, on the other hand, you shouldn't have any problems with
Unix based machines; under Windows, the numeric value won't necessarily
mean much if the file is opened in text mode, but you can convert a
`pos_type` to a `uint64_t` and back without loss of value (unless there
really is significant multibyte state in the original `pos_type`, but I
don't know of any encoding under Windows where this would be the case).

It should be possible to determine at compile time whether `pos_type`
will convert implicitly to an integral type or not, and use this in some
sort of `static_assert`.  I don't think this buys much, however; it
won't determine whether the integral value is in any way usable except
to reconvert back to a `pos_type`.  (It might be some sort of magic
cookie, for example.  But I wouldn't worry about it too much.  The
standard allows a lot of things that no reasonable implementation will
do.  Just keep in mind that even under Windows, the value doesn't always
represent the exact number of bytes which can be read.

Comment: @Ali It should be possible to determine at compile time whether `pos_type` will convert implicitly to an integral type.  I don't think there's anyway of determining whether the results of the conversion are useful in any way (and not e.g. some magic cookie).  In practice, I wouldn't worry too much about it.  The standard allows a lot of things that no reasonable implementation will do.  Just keep in mind that even Windows has a value which doesn't correspond exactly to the number of `char` you would read to advance to that position.

Comment: @Ali It's now part of the answer.